# Center static textfield with jsfl: strange results

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, extending, jsfl

Using Flash CS3, I'm trying to center a static textfield with jsfl after I've altered its text, like so:

```
textElement.setTextString( text );

fl.outputPanel.trace( 'text width: ' + textElement.width );
textElement.x = -( textElement.width / 2 );
fl.outputPanel.trace( 'text x: ' + textElement.x );

fl.outputPanel.trace( 'text height: ' + textElement.height );
textElement.y = -( textElement.height / 2 );
fl.outputPanel.trace( 'text y: ' + textElement.y );
```

The traces all give me the correct numbers. However when I open the relevant symbol with said textfield from the library the textfield's position is off by some amount of pixels:

> x: varies depending on the text width
>   y: always -2, no matter the text height

I've even tried the `_sans` font to see if that made a difference, but it didn't.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I have tested this code on flash CS5.5, so there is no such problem. Perhaps it's CS3 bug.